# Proper positioning of inserted HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I need a hint on how to properly place inserted element:
The initial situation is that the target page lists items in a grid of square tiles, where tiles reflow as the viewport width changes.
What I need is to transform the grid layout to something like tile layout providing more space for more details of each item (one item per line), where the original tile is aligned left and my rectangle element fills the remaining space of the viewport.

The tile is **DIV** wrapped inside enclosing **DIV**. Now I create a new **SPAN** and insert it after the inner **DIV**. However, the **SPAN** is placed not beside but below the inner **DIV** and it's width seems to be fixed to an unknown value. I've workaround it by adding position: relative to outer **DIV** and `position: absolute` to inner **SPAN** and setting it fixed width. It works eventually but as I notice the outer **DIV** doesn't expand if my **SPAN** overgrows it's area (it overflows) - ie. my **SPAN** seems to be excluded from the outer **DIV** though it's hierarchically inside it.

The question is how to organically insert the **SPAN** so that it's adopted by the ancestor, which then grows/shrinks as my element grows, and also inherit it's style.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="width:200px;">
    ..the original tile
  </div>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 0px; margin-right: 10px; width: 500px;">
    ...here comes my content
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: can u plz explain simply?

Comment: Simply: how to place my element BESIDE original DIV, occupying all remainder horizontal space of the enclosing viewport.

Comment: Or this...  
  
`<div style="width: 500px; height: 150px; background-color: black;">  
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: blue;">  
  </div>  
  <div style="width: 350px; height: 150px; background-color: red;">  
  </div>  
</div>`  
  
....hoiw to place the red rectangle to the black area

Answer (score 1):

Try the above code.. plz add the float concepts for this..

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 150px; background-color: black;"> 
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: blue; float: left;"></div> 
  <div style="width: 350px; height: 150px; background-color: red; float: right;"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.   
   more or less works. Problem remaining is the not dynamically adjusting height. I can set min-height to reserve space to fit most cases, but not 100% (lines can wrap etc.). Without height or min-height all items on page blend together (real height of the outer DIV seems to be only several pixels).    
    
Does it have impact on the final arrangement if I choose the right element to be SPAN, DIV or something else and can be the width of the right (red in example) element set dynamically to eat all space right to the blue sq.? (regardless how wide is widest element inside it)